# Dialogflow CX webhook timeout response

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am integrating dialogflow CX with Botcopy using a webhook, my question is if there is a way to add an timeout response, like when the connection to my webhook is down, in Botcopy it stays with the 3 dots indefinitely, and I wanted to check if there is a way to add a response on timeout something like: "The connection is down, please try again later".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was using the in-built event handlers. Check the docs! https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#event-built-in.
Basically where you have your webhook connected, you have to add an event handler like webhook error, that will fire every time your webhook is not found, you can find more related webhook events in the documetation, if you need specific ones like time out, rejected, forbidden, etc.
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).